# Accessing "body" of an iframe document in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to append a "script" element to the body of an iframe, but IE9 thinks that body is undefined.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body
```

Comment: does the iframe refer to a url from the same domain?

Comment: It does not have any url. I am populating the contents using "append"

Answer (score 0):

The function should be getElementsByTagName, the full line is below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body
```

I just tried this in IE9 and it is working correctly for me. If it's still not working on your site perhaps something else is to blame (also try testing the exact same code in chrome and see if that works).

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The code works in Chrome and firefox, just not in IE9

Comment: It works in IE9, try another page such as http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe and putting that line into the console and it works correctly. Or try creating another iframe to a page on your site with content already inside it and see if that works. It must be some other piece of code on the page causing problems as this line works fine.

Comment: To "stop" an iframe from loading in firefox "stop()" is used. Is there anything similar to that in IE ?

Comment: Since the src was blank, loading the content after the iframe is loaded, worked for me.